# How can I select this elements using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="table-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="territory in allTerritories | filter:query">

<div class="table-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="territory in allTerritories | filter:{selected:true}">
```

Does any know how to select above elements using webdriver. The only difference of them is the filter attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cssSelector` to select by attribute partial content

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".table-row[ng-repeat*='query']"));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".table-row[ng-repeat*='selected']"));
```